# Crashes while writing a file into internal storage

Tags: java, android, file

I am developing an application and I have a problem when I try to save a file into the internal storage.

The file is an xml and it's on the res/raw folder on my project. When the application starts, it checks if the file exists or not. If it doesn't exist, it copies the file from the res/raw folder into the internal storage, else it retrieves a field inside the file to check its version and if it's a newer version, it deletes the previous file and copies it again.

Well, the problem is that if I have a new version and I have deleted the previous one, when I'm going to copy it again, it throws an NullPointerExceptcion and I can't find the problem, but I'm using the same code for both situations and I don't know how to solve it.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    private void writeFileToInternalStorage() {  
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        InputStream fXmlFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.partidos);
        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("file.xml");
        if(file.exists()) {
            String resourcesVersion= getFileVersion(fXmlFile);
            String localVersion = getFileVersion(new FileInputStream(file));
            if (!resourcesVersion.equalsIgnoreCase(localVersion)) {
                //file.delete();
                fos = openFileOutput("file.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                copyFile(fos, fXmlFile);
            }
        }
        else {
            fos = openFileOutput("file.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            copyFile(fos, fXmlFile);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }  

    protected void copyFile(OutputStream fos, InputStream fXmlFile) throws IOException {  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
        int bytesRead = 0;  
        while((bytesRead = fXmlFile.read(buffer)) > 0){  
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);  
        }  
    }  

    protected String getFileVersion(InputStream file) {
        String version = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            version = doc.getElementsByTagName("numero").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return version;
    }
```

Any tips for solving it??

PS: The exception is thrown on this statement:

```
while((bytesRead = fXmlFile.read(buffer)) > 0)
```

PS2: This is the code from LogCat:

```
03-03 20:47:07.140: W/System.err(2166): java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
03-03 20:47:07.148: W/System.err(2166):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
03-03 20:47:07.158: W/System.err(2166):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:35)
03-03 20:47:07.168: W/System.err(2166):     at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:573)
03-03 20:47:07.168: W/System.err(2166):     at com.jfma75.myapp.MyApp.copyFile(MyApp.java:291)
03-03 20:47:07.178: W/System.err(2166):     at com.jfma75.myapp.MyApp.writeFileToInternalStorage(MyApp.java:263)
03-03 20:47:07.178: W/System.err(2166):     at com.jfma75.myapp.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:62)
03-03 20:47:07.188: W/System.err(2166):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
03-03 20:47:07.188: W/System.err(2166):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
03-03 20:47:07.198: W/System.err(2166):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-03 20:47:07.198: W/System.err(2166):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
03-03 20:47:07.208: W/System.err(2166):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 20:47:07.208: W/System.err(2166):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 20:47:07.218: W/System.err(2166):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-03 20:47:07.218: W/System.err(2166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:47:07.228: W/System.err(2166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 20:47:07.237: W/System.err(2166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-03 20:47:07.237: W/System.err(2166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-03 20:47:07.248: W/System.err(2166):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try removing `file.delete()`, it will just overwrite the file

Comment: Paste Logcat in the question.

Comment: @Matt, I tried that, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Add the code for `copyFile` to your question. Also, why do you do your initial version check with `new File(dir, "file.xml");` but then just use a relative file name (`openFileOutput("file.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`) for the copy function?

Comment: @Perception, Sorry, that code was from a previous version. Now it's the actual code I'm using. And the copyFile is at the end of the question.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. You open the resource file and hold it in an `InputStream` then you call `String resourcesVersion= getFileVersion(fXmlFile);` which, I guess, is your own private function to get the version. I'm betting you advance the `InputStream` or close it in that function. Then, when you later call `copyFile` the `InputStream` is either consumed or closed. Try just removing that line and put a constant `String resourcesVersion = "versionThatDoesn'tMatch"` just to test the `InputStream`

Comment: you should not keep the file in res/raw folder.. just keep in the assests folder... then write into the internal storage.

Comment: @Matt, I have added the code for the getFileVersion function, and I think you are right, and in some point in this function, it closes the stream, maybe while parsing the xml on dBuilder.parse(file). I have tried to use another stream to check the version, and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added my comment as the answer since it seemed to fix the OP's issue and will close this question:

> I think I know what the problem is. You open the resource file and
>   hold it in an `InputStream` then you call `String resourcesVersion=
>   getFileVersion(fXmlFile);` which, I guess, is your own private function
>   to get the version. I'm betting you advance the `InputStream` or close
>   it in that function. Then, when you later call `copyFile` the
>   `InputStream` is either consumed or closed. Try just removing that line
>   and put a constant `String resourcesVersion = "versionThatDoesn'tMatch";`
>   just to test the `InputStream`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the statement

```
InputStream fXmlFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.partidos);
```

the variable `fXmlFile` is `null`. You can check why that happens.